# Is it possible to do Augmented Reality extended tracking on web using AR.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, augmented-reality, aframe, ar.js

I'm working on a web-based augmented reality project based on THREE.js and AR.js.

The problem I'm facing is that when the "marker" is off my camera, the augmented reality image dissapears or get stuck to the side of my screen.

Vuforia version 2.8 has solved this problem. [Vuforia SDK 2.8: Now with Extended Tracking](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BmxO3SZm9f8)

Does similar kind of solution exist for web augmented reality using AR.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, this is not possible. Somebody asked pretty much the same question on the GitHub tracker of [AR.js](https://github.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/issues/213):

> Honestly, if you want to be able to have AR content without marker
>   images constantly present within view of the camera, there's really
>   only one alternative: SLAM-based AR. e.g. ARKit or ARCore (formerly
>   Tango). These API's are not available for browser, but if you're
>   interested in WebAR without markers, look into:
>   https://github.com/google-ar/WebARonARCore
>   https://github.com/google-ar/WebARonARKit
>    Otherwise, this is your best
>   option if you can handle having markers in view of the camera 100% of
>   the time (if that's what you're asking about). p.s. I've not tried
>   AR.js w/ multi-marker images yet (I've since moved away from it in
>   favor of the above).